# How to make a UIWebView show its text with a custom font?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

It looks like if the font in UIWebView is by default some kind of "Times New Roman". I guess I would have to figure out what font apple uses for [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] ... or is there some intelligent way to do it?

Comment: I think you will need to do that via CSS, the default font of the iPhone is Verdana. Which is not a typical web font, where Times New Roman is.

Comment: No it is not. The system-font is Helvetica for iPhone to iPhone 3GS, and Helvetica Neue for the iPhone 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you inserting text in the UIWebView? Assuming you are setting the HTML you can change the font either by full CSS, inline CSS or deprecated font tags.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        BODY { font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 15px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        Here is some text
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course tweak style and size appropriately.

Comment: awesome! thanks! To made it more clearer for people that doesn't understand this, I added my answer from @JavaCoderEx

Answer (score 0):

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>BODY { font-family: 'Arial-Bold'; font-size: 16px; }</style></head><body>%@</body></html>",htmlBodyString] baseURL:nil];
```